# TCP data communication on Django Channel does not detect event in onmessage

Tags: python, tcp

this is a question from Django.
Send data from an external device -> TCP server -> Django server -> WebSocket client.
Currently, the data received via TCP communication is output to the Django terminal, but it cannot be moved to the WebSocket client.
The problem now is that the Django server returns the data back to the TCP server.
I want to return it from the Django server to the Web Socket client and make it appear on the Web.

Setting, routing, and asgi settings are finished.

TCP_Server.py

```
django_ws_url = "ws:" # WebSocket url
BUFSIZE = 1024

# Websocket 연결 객체를 전역으로 선언
websocket_connection = None

async def send_data(data):
    global websocket_connection

    if websocket_connection is None:
        websocket_connection = await websockets.connect(django_ws_url)

    try:
        json_data = json.dumps({'message': data, 'TLD': 'dadada',})
        await websocket_connection.send(json_data)
        print(json_data)
        
        response = await websocket_connection.recv()
        print(f"Django 서버로부터의 응답: {response}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"에러 발생: {e}")


Django -> consumers.py

class WebSocketClient(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        print('웹소켓 연결됨')

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print(f"disconnect:{close_code}")

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        
        await self.send(text_data = text_data)
        print(f"받은 데이터: {text_data}")
```

base.html

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + '/ws/' + 'socket_path/');

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {

          //alert(event.data);
          // var data = event.data;
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
```